# Calls Generator for Asterisk

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, asterisk, voip

I am trying to measure the capacity of the asterisk server under specific Traffic speed. For that, I would like to use some sort of Call Generator to generate large number of calls and see how Asterisk could handle it. Does anyone of you know any free or open source call generator for Asterisk?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a H.323 channel installed, you can use [Callgen323](https://github.com/willamowius/callgen323).

Answer (score 0):

SIPp is sip testing tool.

Sure it also suitable for asterisk

Yes, it have ability test any sip case and create any CPS/pauses you want.